# Receive Psych::Syntax error when trying to install Rails on OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm new to Ruby/Rails and I've been trying to install Rails under OSX Mavericks but I keep getting the following error:

```
user_name$ gem install rails
/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I've tried to remove RVM and reinstall but I can't seem to find the cause of this error. All research seems to indicate the issue is related to YAML but I haven't even started a project yet so if it's parsing YAML it has to be an internal routine. I get the same message when I try to switch ruby versions as well.

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.1
```

I've reinstalled Xcode, RVM, Ruby, and Homebrew but I keep getting the same error. I've ran ruby -c against all of the .rb files mentioned in the error and they all returned Syntax OK. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your gem configuration file (**.gemrc**) is not **valid yaml** and cause the parse error.

Try to fix the error in **.gemrc** file or just remove it and try again.

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks! How simple. The file only had this line: gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri but after deleting it i was able to install rails.